# Why isn't my ATI driver updating?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-radeon

I went here http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx#2 and downloaded the latest display driver, ran the installer, it said it installed correctly. Then I opened Device Manager, and opened the driver details. It says Driver Version `8.782.0.0`, and driver date `28/09/2010`, but the web page says it should be version `10.10`, so I think I'm behind. I've got some display issues I'd like to be fixed...

Answer (score 3):

The version "10.10" is effectively the driver package release date, as in year **10**, month **10**.  Last months drivers would be 10.9 and so on, and last years driver packages were 9.1 through to 9.12.  The actual driver and program versions within the package can and will vary and quite likely will not agree with the 10.10 version number you see as a customer downloading the drivers.

Admitedly this makes it difficult to ensure that you have the latest version of the drivers installed but you should be able to see the driver date on the same page of device manager as the driver version you found that that should agree with the year.month policy that ATi adopted for their driver releases.

nVidia are slightly better about their driver versions, but not by much.  I have the 258.96 driver version but device manager shows "Driver Version: 8.17.12.5896 " which is basically the driver version with 8.17.1 added to the front for some reason.

Comment: Date says 29/09/10... I guess that's close enough to 10/10/10? Stupid ATI has a bug where my cursor gets distorted, especially after playing full screen games... I should have went with nVidia >.<

Comment: I would expect them to release the drivers (or at least package them) in the last few days before the month number changes so that they can be released on the internet on the first day of the month that they are to be the official drivers for.  The 28th would be a good cutoff day to say "on every 28th of the month we must have drivers ready to be released" as every month has at least 28 days and a script could be made to package the drivers up on that day ready for release on the 1st of the following month.

Answer (score 2):

Version 10.10 is the version of Catalyst Control Center.The driver date of `28/09/2010` is the correct driver date as per the DLLs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Catalyst Control Center, go to the Information Center > Graphics Center. Look at "Catalyst Version". That will display the version you have installed.

The version number which appears in the device manager is the "driver packaging version", I'm not clear on what exactly it is, but it is not the catalyst driver version. I'm *assuming* it has something to do with the installer utility--either the version of the installer utility, or the version of the software used to create the installer.

Comment: I didn't DL the catalyst control center... sounds like bloatware. What could they possibly offer in there that I need beyond a driver?